# Obtain Phrasal Verb by using English Grammatical Relation - Dependency Parser

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have following code which correctly identifies phrasal verb but yielding seems tricky. I want to take the phrasal verb part(compound:prt(come, down) only. I have read Stanford's dependency manual but found no help from there. I have spent two much time figuring out where I am doing mistake.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class dependencyParser {
   public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
      String text = "Come down from the tree.";
      TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
      GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
      LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
      //lp.setOptionFlags(new String[]{"-maxLength", "500", "-retainTmpSubcategories"});
      TokenizerFactory tokenizerFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory( new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
      List wordList = tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(new StringReader(text)).tokenize();
      Tree tree = lp.apply(wordList);



System.out.println(tree);

  GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree);
  Collection<TypedDependency> typedDependencies = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed();
 // System.out.println(tdl);
 // Main.writeImage(tree,tdl, "image.png",3);
  System.out.println();

  for(TypedDependency td : gs.typedDependencies()) {
  if(td.reln().equals(EnglishGrammaticalRelations.PHRASAL_VERB_PARTICLE)) {
              System.out.println( td);
  }
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you print the list of typed dependencies? Also, is there a reason to not use the CoreNLP pipeline with the annotators set to "tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse"? This should give you a `SemanticGraph` object for each sentence on the `CollapsedDependenciesCoreAnnotation` key, which is generally an easier data structure to work with.

Comment: It prints dependency tree. Um I have just started working with stanford nlp and there is no any reason behind not using CoreNLP pipeline. An example would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, this doesn't answer the question why your code isn't finding the 'compound:prt' edge, but you can get the tree easier with: `Properties prop s = new Properties(); props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse"); Annotation ann = new Annotation("Come down from the tree"); StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props); pipeline.annotate(ann); SemanticGraph tree = ann.get(SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0).get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);`

Comment: How would I get compound:prt edge by using your example?

Comment: Either by looping over the vertex set, and then the outgoing edges, or using something like semgrex.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I have been working on it since last couple of days, got it after experimenting with Semanticgraph. I just lacked basic graph and NLP knowledge!